# UIActivityViewController Flickr Sharing - No Flickr option appears

Tags: ios, ios7, flickr, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to use the UIActivityViewController Flickr sharing in iOS 7 but the Flickr icon does not appear in the sharing sheet.  I feel like I am missing something basic.

I am testing on an iPhone 5S.
I am logged into a Flickr account on the device.
The same share sheet displays and shares properly with Facebook, Twitter, Email , MMS, and AirDrop.
The photos app on the device displays the Flickr icon in the photos app sharing sheet and can share successfully to the phone Flickr account.
I am sure that I am not listing Flickr in the excluded activities for the UIActivityViewController.
I have tried with both standard UIActivityViewController and the RDActivityViewController subclasses.

Is there something additional required for Flickr sharing?  or could someone confirm that they have seen this work in their own app.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flickr share with `UIActivityViewController` will only work if you are sharing a image. 
So in your array with activity items there should be at least one image.

Make sure that the image is of type `UIImage`:

```
NSArray *shareItems = @[someImage, @"Text of the messages"];

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareItems applicationActivities:nil];
```

---

Exmple of how it looks: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jpjmnuqbktqgb8s/FlickTest.png

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm that I am sharing an image.  The image shares in mail, Airdrop, Facebook, Twitter, and Message.  One thing I tried was having only an image in the shareItems array but it made no difference.

Comment: Weird, I'm also sharing an `UIImage` with title in one of my apps and it works just a expected.

Comment: OK that is helpful.  You are the first person that confirmed that it should work.  I will try a different device with a different Flickr account.

Comment: I got it working.  I was including a URL in the shareItems along with the image which causes the icon not to display.  I must have done the test of attempting to share only an image wrong because sharing only an image is possible and displays the Flickr icon.  I still can not get the RDActivityViewController implementation to display the Flickr icon.  Have you ever used that class.

Comment: for me the filckr doesn't appear either

Comment: The crash is being caused by an NSString I included in my activityItems.